# Rep amount links inconsistent

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reputation, hyperlinks

Rep amount links are inconsistent and it causes me to forget how to get to the two different pages. The rep amount link in the top bar goes to your rep statistics pages. The rep amount link on your user page goes to rep privileges. I understand that if you're already on your user page, you have an obvious tab to use. However, I keep using the link in the topbar by mistake.

Any reason these should remain inconsistent?

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know they changed the profile rep to be a link. FYI, at one point the top bar rep also pointed at the privileges page; it was probably consistent back then.

Comment: @Popular Demand I remember that. I'm sure they changed the top bar rep to point to rep pages since that's more useful to the user.
However I'd like there to be an obvious rep privileges page link. It doesn't really matter where it's located, since I won't use it much.

Comment: For what it's worth, there's a "privileges" page at the top of the "new" drop down that comes up when you hover on your username.  But I definitely agree that clicking on your rep should be consistent across pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the next build the reputation on your profile will link to the reputation tab in the profile, the same as the top bar currently does.

Comment: [While you're poking around the profile page changing links...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94486/comment-links-on-responses-tab-do-not-work-correctly-when-the-comment-is-hidden)

Comment: @Tim - Not a quick fix, but I'll add it to my list, as it actually goes with another upcoming feature.

Comment: Ah, sorry for assuming it was. I'm intrigued by what this upcoming feature might be though, keep up the good work! :)