# Jump directly to comment from global inbox link

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, global-inbox

Similar to the way that the global inbox jumps directly to the answer, it would be helpful to be able to jump directly to the comment as indicated in the global inbox.

The issue is that sometimes a comment is hidden underneath the add / show more comments and if there are a lot of comments (which happens quite often on the skeptics site) I need to first skim through the available comments to see if that comment hasn't been voted up then open the link then find the actual comment.

This is also helpful on a mobile interface to reduce the number of clicks when I want a quick update on one of my posts.

It appears from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment) that it is possible to link to comments.

Comment: So you want it to auto-expand when we jump to a hidden comment?

Comment: @jcolebrand - That's correct.

Comment: Comment linking is possible, but intentionally not supported, so I'm not sure how likely it is that they'll go for this. For a userscript alternative, see [SE Modifications](http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/). Also, (for linking purposes) there's a [semi-related bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94486).

Comment: This is unlikely to ever happen. We want you to at least glance at the rest of the content as well. Comments != chat.

Comment: @Cody that doesn't make sense as a comment is in reply to something you already wrote so you know what 'the rest of the content' is.

Comment: Other people frequently comment in the interim. There's no guarantee that the discussion is limited to just you and the other person. This is a useless feature. It already links to the specific post in question. How hard is it to just read the content and reply accordingly?

Comment: @Cody - Just asking for something that would help my user experience as its something I use almost daily. I hate asking questions in meta; can't get a straight answer without some passive aggressive reply from some mod or super user. Comments are what they are, a useless feature is providing a link which doesn't link to the right place.

Comment: Not sure if that was meant to be a passive aggressive reply to my comment. Note that I'm neither a moderator on Meta, nor am I a very active participant on [Super User](http://www.superuser.com/). The reason you "can't get a straight answer", though, is because you're making a feature request. I'm not sure what type of answer you're looking for, other than one of the developers saying "this has been implemented". That's relatively rare, and it's even less rare that it happens overnight. You'll have a lot better experience on Meta if you try to chill out and take objections in stride.

Comment: related: [Auto expand comments of specific answer when browsing directly to that answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71182/auto-expand-comments-of-specific-answer-when-browsing-directly-to-that-answer)

Answer (score 1):

<s>The fact that one [cannot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment/27319#27319) reliably link to comments aside: *(update: one [can](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94486/comment-links-on-responses-tab-do-not-work-correctly-when-the-comment-is-hidden/107511#107511) now)*</s>

Direct linking <s>would</s> requires listing all comments in the Inbox by themselves. <s>Currently</s> Previously comments were grouped together, which kept the list short. I liked that.

Since this was implemented I need to scroll in my Inbox itself, seeing the same post repeated many times. Too bad, I feel:

[image: The same post repeated and repeated and repeated...]

That said: it might <s>be</s> have been nice if the comments were expanded when following a link form the Inbox. I don't feel a need to automatically scroll to the specific comment then, but I wouldn't mind automatic scrolling to the first (oldest) comment to which the Inbox notification applies.

(Likewise: [your](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149428/xiaohouzi79?tab=responses#rpage_1-rfilter_comments) responses tab and [your](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149428/xiaohouzi79?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_comments) activity tab *do* link to comments directly, but only for comments on answers. For that to work, hidden comments [are unhidden if required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94486/comment-links-on-responses-tab-do-not-work-correctly-when-the-comment-is-hidden/107511#107511) too.)