# Please bring back the grouping of replies in the inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

It used to be that when you had multiple consecutive comments on the same post, they appeared in a single entry in your inbox.

> 42 comments on **The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange**

I don't know when this changed, but now every comment is its separate entry.

[image: inbox screenshot]

Thus, if you happen to participate in a high-profile thread (*shudder* reply to Jeff on MSO *shudder*, your inbox is shot for a while.

Please bring back the former behavior of grouping consecutive comments on the same post, and answers on the same question.

Comment: It changed once they started linking directly to each comment. I guess there's no particular reason it can't link to just the last comment in the given thread, though, and roll up the count.

Comment: For reference: it was changed to support [Jump directly to comment from global inbox link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98958/jump-directly-to-comment-from-global-inbox-link). Also note that the Responses tab in one's profile already lists each comment by itself just fine too.

Comment: Admit it.  You just love the idea of having groupies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Grouping by post for multiple comments has been restored (on the next build).

Comment: I kinda liked it ungrouped since I could see snippets of every comment I received (given that I have a relatively low inbox activity).  But I understand the concern for grouping them.  Could it be made so they're grouped but can be expanded by clicking on something (an arrow or on the `# comments` part)?  Would this be separate request worthy?

Comment: “17 comments on …” Aaah, that's better. Thanks!