# Make the grouped inbox messages expandable

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox

This is in response to this request: [Please bring back the grouping of replies in the inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124022/please-bring-back-the-grouping-of-replies-in-the-inbox)

So it was recently ungrouped and now will be grouped back again.  As I said in my comment to Geoff:

> I kinda liked it ungrouped since I could see snippets of every comment I received (given that I have a relatively low inbox activity). But I understand the concern for grouping them. Could it be made so they're grouped but can be expanded by clicking on something (an arrow or on the # comments part)?

**My request is to make it so the grouping could be expanded to show more of the comments**.  Not necessarily all of the comments in the group, but more than just the most recent one (I propose the most recent 5 sounds reasonable).

Perhaps there could be a little expansion triangle that could be clicked and more messages could be brought in underneath.  Maybe make the `# comments` part clickable to add more of the comments of the group.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just click through to the post though? Then you get to see *all* the comments...

Comment: I do actually anyway, but then again if this were implemented, I wouldn't have to navigate to the question just to be able to see them. Seeing all of the post with all the answers and other comments I probably wouldn't care about can be distracting at times.

Comment: Sometimes you see an inbox message about a comment that has since been deleted. *That*'s when I wish inbox messages were expandable!

Comment: This request seems especially useful/necessary given the [recent inbox improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384148/inbox-improvements-are-live), since each notification is marked read/unread separately but the grouped notifications are not visible until refreshing the inbox.