# Inbox enhancement - Expand activity on a question

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make the grouped inbox messages expandable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124037/make-the-grouped-inbox-messages-expandable)

I would like the notification in the inbox to be expandable (via a treeview or some such) so that if I have multiple notifications on a single question or answer, I can jump right to all of the new ones.  For example, I logged in today and saw that I had 2 notifications.  These notifications were new answers on a question that already has ~20 answers (and the notifications were combined to a single line).  I'd love to be able to expand the aggregate notifications, see that 2 answers had been added (or, for example, an answer and a comment) and click them individually.

Comment: Doesn't the notification notice jump you right to where it took place?

Comment: @Makoto - If I have two new answers to the same question, it shows as a single line and clicking it takes me to the most recent of the two answers.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the idea of grouping. It's not as much about taking you to the location of the comment/update as it is in knowing that 2 of the 3 notifications that I see in the list are actually on the same page.

I find it much easier to just look for the other notification than it is to click the 2nd notification and then wait for the page I'm already on to reload. That, to me, seems like a waste of time and bandwidth.

Of course, I have pretty slow bandwidth for where I live. It's 1 Mbps download speed. Also, I'm on an older computer where things load slowly sometimes. Perhaps for the majority of users on the latest technologies, this isn't a problem.