# Reputation Score link on profile page no longer goes to the rep+privileges details page?

Tags: support, profile-page, privileges-page

It used to be that on your profile page, if you clicked on your reputation score just below your avatar icon, you'd be taken to a page about reputation and privileges.

This seems to have changed though, and clicking on your rep score there now takes you through to the normal "Reputation" tab.

The page you used to be taken to had lots of interesting information on it about what privileges you had earned, and which ones were coming up. The new link is to something you can easily get at anyway.

I can't spot anything about this change in the [recent feature changes list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange), does anyone know why it was done, and how I can get at the old page to see how close I am to getting the next set of privileges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reputation link on your user profile was [updated to be consistent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93564/rep-amount-links-inconsistent/106017#106017) with the reputation link at the top of every page, which points to the reputation tab. But fear not, you can still access the privileges page from the profile drop down:

[image: Privileges link]

Answer (score 3):

You can click on that link in your profile card

http://phpcode.eu/images/1316824484.png