# Unable to see a list of my earned privileges

Tags: support, privileges-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the link to my privileges page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67333/where-is-the-link-to-my-privileges-page)

When I get 2 or more privileges, I see the banner:

> **You've earned the create chat rooms privilege and 1 other**

Where can I find a privileges link with which I can see all of my privileges?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Why is there no link to /privileges on profile page but a link in profile card?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109424)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I was going to tell you that the Jeff's answer was no longer true...and then I saw that you already addressed that =)  Upvote'ddd to push it up on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do this is to hover over your username at the top of each page, and then click the "privileges" link:

[image: Privileges Link]

Comment: does 100% means I got that privilege?

Comment: @Balaswamyvaddeman Correct!  And the other percentages show (approximately) how close you are to getting the other privileges.

Comment: tx @jadarnel127

Comment: @Balaswamyvaddeman You're welcome.  Also, I find it ironic that this answer gave me the "Established User" privilege =)