# Please bring back the link to my privileges in the profile page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, privileges

In the old style one had a direct link to the personal list of unlocked and locked privileges:

> [image]

I still find it via the help center, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges,
and I do find a link from my profile to the next available privilege.

I you think it would be reasonable to link not the next available privilege (which is of course nice too) but rather the entire list.

Comment: I can't remember there was a link before. I always used the help center.

Comment: @Pat oh my, blonde moment. Disregard! The previous design indeed contains a direct link to privileges list. :(

Comment: @Pat great minds think alike! Just added a screenshot. :-)

Comment: Did they run out of space maybe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The links at the top of your old profile have moved to a new major tab called [Edit profile & settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current). You can find the functionality on that tab as categories on the left of your screen. The option Privileges can be found as the last option in that list.

[image: profile]

You can also click on the area under Next privilege on your [activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) which brings you to your next privilege. From there it is easy to navigate to the full list.

[image: privilege]

The full [privilege list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) is also linked from the main page of the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Why is it stuck so far away? Did they run out of space maybe?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I've edited my answer to include an explanation how  your cheese was moved

Comment: Well, it's still two clicks away vs. one click in previous design. Harder to reach the cheese.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that will keep the mice away.

Comment: This is a horrible solution, having to choose _Edit_ to look up something I cannot edit!

Comment: My comment is not intended to criticise you, but only the situation as it is. I quite like the proposal on [why-is-there-no-link-to-privileges-on-profile-page-but-a-link-in-profile-card](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109424/why-is-there-no-link-to-privileges-on-profile-page-but-a-link-in-profile-card?rq=1), but really I would prefer to _see_ ‘Privileges’ somewhere.