# Why is the link to my Privileges under the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, privileges

It took me a while to find my privileges - this was the first time I had needed to look at them. I has assumed that they would be accessible from "Activity" tab of my profile, in particular somewhere in the Reputation box with the graph showing progress (as that is also where the next privilege is displayed), or maybe the "Profile" tab.

However, I was a bit surprised to find it under the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab, which I clicked on as a last resort. I am not editing anything when I wish to view my privileges, and neither is it a setting that I can change. The Profile or Activity tags seem a more logical place for it.

---

#### Addendum

As Rene's comment points out, in the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253917/158100) to [Please bring back the link to my privileges in the profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253915/please-bring-back-the-link-to-my-privileges-in-the-profile-page/253917), clicking the area under "Next privilege" on the activity tab (highlighted in Rene's answer):

[image: Click on next privilege]

takes you to your next privilege. Rene's answer then goes on to say:

> From there it is easy to navigate to the full list.

Clicking on "Learn more>", I get taken to [Help Center > Privileges > Cast Close And Reopen Votes](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). From there, I can get to the full list by clicking the "Privileges" link in the right hand side bar.

I think what stumped me was the last step of clicking the "Privileges" link. I was hesitant to click it as I expected it to takes me to a further explanation of the privileges (similar to the "Cast Close And Reopen Votes" page) rather than the list that I was actually after.

[image: My privileges]

I don't know why, but I think rewording the link from "Privileges" to "*My* Privileges" would be more intuitive, and would have steered me to my desired destination quicker. Or better still, somewhere on the Activity tab, near the "Next privilege" box, as it would save two clicks. However, the latter suggestion could make things a little busy, in that area of the UI.

Please note that this is not a criticism, it is just my feedback as a new user, you understand.

Comment: You can reach it from your activity page as explained by me [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253917/158100), just click the area under next privilege. It is also linked in the help center which is more logical.

Comment: @Rene - Thanks for that explanation, I understand the route to take now. I've updated the question with an addendum.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with the OP, I didn't want to click on "Learn more", since the link took me to some help&answer site, which I didn't want to go from my profile, I was looking for my privileges. I like @HackerKarma's solution or simply adding a link to "My privileges" underneath the "Learn more" would be also good enough for me.

Comment: Hear, hear! See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238885/clicking-privileges-on-another-users-profile-should-not-show-me-my-own-privil, which could affect the design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per OP quote:

> However, I was a bit surprised to find it under the "Edit Profile &
>   Settings" tab, which I clicked on as a last resort. I am not editing
>   anything when I wish to view my privileges, and neither is it a
>   setting that I can change. The Profile or Activity tags seem a more
>   logical place for it.

Yes, I agree with the OP here. But, we could make this simple by giving a one-click access to user's "**privileges**" earned area.

I would like to suggest the following little UI change (see screenshot #1 below) in the "**Reputation**" box. If you notice, there is a reward ribbon [image] icon (shown *just for an example purpose* only) on the right side of the next-privilege progress bar. Upon clicking on this icon, it should display the user's "[Privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)" area. Also, it would be great if we could add a tooltip message on the ribbon icon, say for example; "Check your privileges..." (again, it's just an example purpose).

**Here is the mock-up version for "Reputation" box:**

> [image]

I used the "**Badges**" box as an example for creating the above mock-up. Here is the **screenshot of current "badges" box**:

> [image]

Notice the little tiny "**gear icon**" (which allows user to "select a badge to track") on the right side of next-badge progress bar. This was an excellent UI change and a good use of the little screen estate available next to the progress bar. Nicely placed, no cluttering of any kind. I borrowed the same design concept to create my mock-up for the *reputation* box. The icons are very commonly used in today's UI design. They are visually pleasing, eye catchy and enhance the aesthetic appeal of a UI design.

Please share your thoughts, ideas or any suggestions.

Comment: I think that the ribbon is a nice touch, and as you say, it ties in nicely with the gear icon in the badges box. It would add a certain symmetry to the UI.

Comment: @Greenonline Thanks. I'm glad to hear that you liked it.